# How to set correct 32 bit dependencies for mexw32 file

Tags: c++, matlab

I am constructing a 32bit .mexw32 from a cpp file in Matlab 32 bit on windows 7 64bit os. Although it is successfully generated to file, when I run it I get the error `Invalid MEX-file 'PCLview_organised.mexw32': The
specified module could not be found.`

With Dependency Walker I realize that it resorts to 64bit dll's instead of 32 which results in compatibility issues. [image] How can this be fixed ??? I have unsucessfully tried adding the windows/syswow64 to environment variables but somehow, the 64 bit dll's still get picked up.

Comment: That error is because it is expecting a MEX compiled file called `PCLview_organised` but it can't find it.  Do you have a C/C++ file named `PCLview_organized`?  If you do, make sure you MEX compile this, then try it again.

Comment: I have mex compiled it and it is safely placed in the working folder. However it is not found due to the compatibility described earlier with the screenshot